# Isometric and conformally equivalent surfaces in $\mathbb R^d$ with the same boundary

Tags: riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces, curves-and-surfaces

Let $X$ be a compact smooth surface in $\mathbb R^d$ with smooth boundary $\partial X$. Is it possible to find another smooth surface $Y$ in $\mathbb R^d$ such that $\partial X = \partial Y$ and $Y$ is isometric (resp. conformally equivalent) to $X$? The metric is supposed to be induced from $\mathbb R^d$.

The same question for holomorphic chains (in particular, for complex curves with boundary) in $\mathbb C^d$ has the negative answer: if two compact holomorphic chains have the same boundary, they are equal. Locally it is the statement of the Cauchy integral formula from complex analysis and globaly it is the result of Harwey-Shiffman 1975 ( Proposition 3.5).

Answer (score 1):

Take a sphere $S$, and a 2-plane $P$ intersecting $S$, not tangent to $S$. Cut off the cap of points on one side of $P$ from $S$; call the sphere minus that cap $X$. Reflect $X$ in $S$. Call that $Y$.

Comment: Photo: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Double_bubble.png

Comment: But formally the boundary of your $Y$ is the boundary of $X$ with the opposite orientation

Comment: Identify $X$ with $Y$ by shrinking $X$ through a family of spherical caps, all with the same boundary, with curvature shrinking to zero, when $X$ becomes a disk. Then grow $X$ into $Y$ through a family of spherical caps, all with the same boundary. You get a diffeomorphism from $X$ to $Y$, up to the boundary, and an isometry. It doesn't match up mean curvature vectors.